# Learning Angular and what decides the home screen html

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

In Angular 8 the Routes app-routing.module.ts is straight forward and if the app.component.html have links and text the app can be used right.

In my study I came across and app that had an app.component.html like this;

```
<body>
  <app-nav-menu></app-nav-menu>
  <div class="container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</body>
```

I see here that the `HomeComponent` is loaded when app start and understand the declarations and setups for that here in the app.module.ts,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { AddContactComponent } from './add-contact/add-contact.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    AddContactComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'contact/:id', component: ContactComponent },
      { path: 'new-contact', component: AddContactComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but where does the `HomeComponent` set to be the router-outlet start page, is it at the

```
RouterModule.forRoot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly! On bootstrapping 'AppComponent', router module evaluates the incoming browser path expression and delegate control to respective Angular Component.

```
/*https://<domain-name>:<optional-port>/           - Will take you to HomeComponent

https://<domain-name>:<optional-port>/contact      - Will take you to ContactComponent with route param id:undefined or null
https://<domain-name>:<optional-port>/contact:100  - Will take you to ContactComponent with route param id:100*/

RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      ...])
```

Routing is all based on our configurations using, `RouterModule.forRoot()`.

Comment: Thanks, but what decides when Routs `'@angular/router'` are used like `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)`, what page is the start page?

Comment: app.component.html is acting like layout or master page which indeed a starting page of any Angular 2+ application. `@angular/router` just tries to engage the target component (*here, HomeComponent*) to produce some html content which would be placed in <router-outlet></router-outlet> based on incoming-path-expression. Rest of HTML elements stay like master page do.